# How to use more than one USB controller simultaneously

Tags: game-controllers

I have two identical SNES style USB controllers that I plug in to my android HDMI box, trying to play SNES emulators etc using Super retro 16. However I cannot get it to recognise each controller separately. One controller ends up controlling both players together.

What configuration options on Android am I missing?